# How do I format to only include decimal if there are any

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best way to format a decimal if I only want decimal displayed if it is not an integer.

Eg:

```
decimal amount = 1000M
decimal vat = 12.50M
```

When formatted I want:

```
Amount: 1000 (not 1000.0000)
Vat: 12.5 (not 12.50)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
    decimal one = 1000M;
    decimal two = 12.5M;

    Console.WriteLine(one.ToString("0.##"));
    Console.WriteLine(two.ToString("0.##"));
```

Comment: Its' important to remember you've gotta include as many # signs as you want to display decimal places if you use this method.

Answer (score 25):

**Updated following comment by  user1676558**

Try this:

```
decimal one = 1000M;    
decimal two = 12.5M;    
decimal three = 12.567M;    
Console.WriteLine(one.ToString("G"));    
Console.WriteLine(two.ToString("G"));
Console.WriteLine(three.ToString("G"));
```

For a decimal value, the default precision for the "G" format specifier is 29 digits, and  fixed-point notation is always used when the precision is omitted, so this is the same as "0.#############################".

Unlike "0.##" it will display all significant decimal places (a decimal value can not have more than 29 decimal places).

The "G29" format specifier is similar but can use scientific notation if more compact (see [Standard numeric format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5)).

Thus:

```
decimal d = 0.0000000000000000000012M;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("G"));  // Uses fixed-point notation
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("G29"); // Uses scientific notation
```

Comment: G29 uses scientific notation in certain scenarios (refer to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5)), 0.############################# is like a G29 that doesn't revert to scientific notation.

Comment: Sure, and sorry to be a pest. G actually preserves trailing zeros unlike G29 and 0.#############################. G shows the decimal 'as is', so to speak. G29 removes trailing zeros but can also revert to scientific notation if it's more compact. 0.############################# does not revert to scientific notation but does remove trailing zeros. The decimal 0.000010m can demonstrate these differences.

Comment: `12.0M.ToString("G")` outputs `12.0` whereas `12.0M.ToString("G2")` outputs `12`